# How to debug inside function of a jquery

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

My issue here is reading or understanding the arguments that were passed into a callback function in jQuery code, for example I have the below code:

```
                  $("#" + someId).sparkline('html', {
                        type: 'bar',
                        chartRangeMin: 0,
                        chartRangeMax: 100,
                        barColor: '#8AC007',
                        colorMap: range_map,
                        resultObj: sparklineTooltip[someId],
                            tooltipFormatter:
                                function(sp, options, fields) { 
                                    var tooltipElem = "";
                                    $.each(fields,
                                        function(i, field) {
                                            var tooltipObj =  options.get('resultObj')[11-field.offset][field.offset].split(",");
                                            tooltipElem = createTooltipElement(tooltipObj);
                                            field.tooltipFormat = tooltipElem;
                                        })

                                    return tooltipElem;
                                }
                    });
```

What is the best way to debug inside the `tooltipFormatter` callback function? I want to get the debug point to the line `var tooltipObj =  options.get('resultObj')[11-field.offset] field.offset].split(",");`. I want to see what values both of these arguments have inside the function: `options` and `fields`. Are the **options, fields** some sort of standard arguments in sparkline? From the documentation of jquery sparkline I see this:

[image]

Comment: Place a debugging breakpoint on exactly that line in the browser's script debugger?

Comment: Or add `debugger;` to the script to programatically do the same thing.

Comment: I tried that - the debugger doesn't stop at that line... The debugging works differently with call back functions I think

Answer (score 2):

There's a debugger function in JavaScript, used like this:

```
function multiply(x) {
  debugger;
  return x * 2;
}
```

It should be what you need; it allows you to essentially "pause" your script and see the value of all variables at that point in time. You could place that within the function you're calling to see what the arguments represent.

[Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: I tried it didn't work. It is still not stopping at that line.

Comment: Could you show me what you’re doing when adding the debugger statement